# android/opengles alpha textures not semitransparent but binary transparent

Tags: android, opengl-es, transparency, textures, alphablending

I am drawing some textures with alpha channel, but when they are displayed it looks like the alpha channel is only binary.  So a pixel is either transparent or opaque, although in the texture file itself the pixel is half-transparent.  The blending is set up like this:

```
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_ONE, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Is there a workaround for this problem?

The above shows how it should be like, and the below shows how it is:

[image]

Comment: What internalFormat are you using in that texture?

Comment: Can I get more information on the PNG? Like how was it saved?

Comment: it was saved with photoshop, and believe me, it has an alpha channel with varying values. it is not binary transparent.

Comment: Would you post a link to the PNG file so I can test it with the same resources? Only if possible.

Comment: http://deviantsart.com/upload/2757n63.png but again, i dont think the PNG is the problem, because i use PNGs like this a lot in normal GL rendering and they work fine.

Comment: I didn't state that the PNG is the problem I just wanted to have the same resources to be able to reproduce the result. ;)

Comment: @clamp PNG is not an internal format. The internal format is a parameter to the glTexImage2D call. What value are you using for that parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);    
gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_ALPHA_BITS);
//draw...
gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_ALPHA_BITS);
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  However in my case it is also working without GL_ALPHA_BITS calls

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it's using alpha testing instead of alpha blending, which would explain the thresholding behaviour. Although it isn't enabled by default, it might be worth to try:

```
gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_ALPHA_TEST);
```

Comment: alpha test is already disabled and i also depth sort all the objects i am painting

Answer (score 0):

What surface format are you using for your GLSurfaceView? Is it a translucent (not transparent) format?

```
surfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

Also the EGL settings must have alpha support set. This will give you the best of quality...

```
surfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
```

Edit:
Another thought is that perhaps you didn't upload the image to OpenGL in a translucent format with glTexImage2D?

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing the PNG to a GL texture that only has 1 bit of alpha, such as 16-bit 5-5-5-1 format? This would cause the behavior above.